# Flutter - only get assets

Tags: flutter, dart, assets, pubspec

Is there a command or a way to only get assets in flutter.
I work with a legacy flutter code and when I add extra assets and hit save it gives me a prompt:
"Some packages are missing or out of date, would you like to get them now?"
If I say yes it get the assets but also latest dart version and it just completely messes up the code.
I only need extra assets not a newest packages.
Is there any way to accomplish that in flutter?

Comment: You can fix the lib version when you dont use '^' in your pubspec
Ex.: ```geolocator: 7.6.2``` instead of ```geolocator: ^7.6.2```

Comment: Yeah that actually is good, but I was more thinking about Dart sdk. I think the correct solution to that would be something like that in pubspec.yaml:

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"